# Vertical align corrupts break line

Tags: html, css

I have this page which is a page for showing a product and what I'm trying to do is to have the image of the product on the right side and on the left side having the name, price and add to cart button. I use vertical align on img so the text goes to top but doing this means I have to use display inline-block so I can't use block to make the texts go one every line. I also tried to use `<br>` but it makes the text go under the image.

```css
* {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: Iransans;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        * a:link {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        body {
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
            height: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
        }
        article{
            background-color: #ffffff;
            width: 85%;
            padding: 20px 20px;
            text-align: right;
            direction: rtl;
            border-radius: 3px;
            margin: 20px auto;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        }
        img{
            border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
        }
        .name{
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin: 5px 50px;
            padding: 0 10px;
            border-right: 5px solid #13bf19;
        }
        .price{
            display: inline-block;
        }
```

```html
<body>
<article>
<img src="https://images.food52.com/8yjdBI07757aOjYnJJNPiI7XsPA=/375x0/fca306c8-d23b-46b6-8ce0-c0744830f596--2018-0716_sin_porcelain-paper-mug_silo_ty-mecham_001_1-.jpg" width="100" height="100">
<div class="name">name of product</div><br>
<div class="price">$59.99</div>
</article>
</body>
```

And this is what I'm trying to make:

```css
.image{
margin: 0 50px;
float: right;
border: 1px solid black;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}
.text{
float: right;

}
```

```html
<body>
<span class="image">IMAGE</span>
<span class="text">text</span><br>
<span class="text">text</span>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of adding 
 outside div , add it inside.

```css
* {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: Iransans;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        * a:link {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        body {
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
            height: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
        }
        article{
            background-color: #ffffff;
            width: 85%;
            padding: 20px 20px;
            text-align: right;
            direction: rtl;
            border-radius: 3px;
            margin: 20px auto;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        }
        img{
            border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
        }
        .name{
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin: 5px 50px;
            padding: 0 10px;
            border-right: 5px solid #13bf19;
        }
        .price{
            display: inline-block;
        }
```

```html
<article>
<img src="https://images.food52.com/8yjdBI07757aOjYnJJNPiI7XsPA=/375x0/fca306c8-d23b-46b6-8ce0-c0744830f596--2018-0716_sin_porcelain-paper-mug_silo_ty-mecham_001_1-.jpg" width="100" height="100">
<div class="name">name of product<br><div class="price">$59.99</div></div><br>

</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

just style it

```css
* {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: Iransans;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        * a:link {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        body {
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
            height: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
        }
        article{
            background-color: #ffffff;
            width: 85%;
            padding: 20px 20px;
            text-align: right;
            direction: rtl;
            border-radius: 3px;
            margin: 20px auto;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
        }
        img{
            border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
        }

        .name{
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin: 5px 50px;
            padding: 0 10px;
            border-right: 5px solid #13bf19;
        }
        .price{
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: normal;
        }
```

```html
<body>
<article>
<img src="https://images.food52.com/8yjdBI07757aOjYnJJNPiI7XsPA=/375x0/fca306c8-d23b-46b6-8ce0-c0744830f596--2018-0716_sin_porcelain-paper-mug_silo_ty-mecham_001_1-.jpg" width="100" height="100">
<div class="name"><h2>name of product</h2><h3 class="price">$59.99</h3></div>
</article>
</body>
```